# How record multiple website Action

Tags: jmeter

How record multiple website Action 
I have a one master company and have a multiple slave company so, I want to record all action for all website for one test plan

Comment: Please add more details. Do you want to record URL1, URL2, URL3 etc in the same test plan?

Comment: Yes, I want to record URL1, URL2, URL3 etc in the same test plan.

Comment: Posted the answer. Please check and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record multiple URLs in the same test plan. Assume that you want to record below three websites.

1. http://example1.com
2. http://example2.com
3. http://example3.com

### In JMeter

Create three **loop controllers** (or any controllers of your choice) in your test plan as shown below.

[image: Test Plan Design]

Before you start recording `http://example1.com`, go to **Recording Controller** and select the `Example1` controller as shown below.

[image: Select the controller]

Start your recording.

Once you are done with the recording of `http://example1.com`, go back to **JMeter** and **change the controller** to `Example 2` and **repeat** the above steps.

Ditto for `Example 3` as well.

In this way, you can multiple URLs within the same test plan.

### **Alternate Method**

Another simpler way is to use [Blazemeter Chrome Addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) to record JMeter tests. Install the addon in Chrome browser and simply record your flow across multiple URLs. While exporting you can check which URLs to include/exclude.